# Handling S3 Bucket Trigger Event in Lambda Using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The AWS Lambda handler has a signature of

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

However, I cannot find any documentation as to the event's structure when the trigger is an S3 Bucket receiving a put

I thought that it might be defined in the s3 console, but couldn't find that there.

Anyone have any leads?

Comment: S3 event notification structure http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html and configuring notifications http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Answer (score 7):

The event from S3 to Lambda function will be in json format as shown below,

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "eventTime":The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, when S3 finished processing the request,
         "eventName":"event-type",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-user-who-caused-the-event"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"ip-address-where-request-came-from"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
            "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":object-size,
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, 
                   only used with PUTs and DELETEs"            
            }
         }
      },
      {
          // Additional events
      }
   ]
}
```

here is the link for aws documentation which can guide you. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: Just want to correct the URL. It should be : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Answer (score 2):

I think your easiest route is just to experiment quickly:

1. Create a bucket using the console
2. Create a lambda that is triggered by puts to the bucket using the console
3. Ensure you choose the default execution role, so you create cloudwatch logs
4. The lambda function just needs to "print(event)" when called, which is then logged
5. Save an object to the bucket

You'll then see the event structure in the log - its pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this URL to get Event Message Structure: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Ah sorry. This question had been answered by Chan Dru above. I just want to correct the URL which links to AWS document. I also commented under the answer.